# iPhone : form like new contact

Tags: iphone, uitableview, contacts, grouped-table

I have some questions about the Apple iPhone Contact App. I want to use the same methode to create and modify information.

Here's two pics :

[alt text http://grab.by/4ZjQ](http://grab.by/4ZjQ)
[alt text http://grab.by/4ZjR](http://grab.by/4ZjR)

So we have the creation and the edition. The form looks like an UITableView with a groupedStyle but I don't know how to re-creat all of this. Have you got an idea or a tutorial that might explain how to do it ?

Thanks a lot !

Comment: I have been looking for a detailed answer to this too.  Did you ever get a good answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the top bit is a UIView with a UIImageView and a UITableView, this view is set as the header of the overall UITableView.

As for the editing, you need to swap out the UILabel, with a UITextField, which has the same frame, and font-size. move the content from one view to another.

Comment: This worked for me. I might I add that the HeaderFooter sample code by Apple was helpful too.

Answer (score 2):

Create a UIView that is a line, then add it as a subview to the cell

```
//in cellForRowAtIndexPath
UIView *lineView = [[UIView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(80,0,1,44)];
lineView.backgroundColor = [UIColor lightGreyColor];
[cell addSubview:lineView];
```

Answer (score 1):

Customizing the UITableview is definitely the way to go.  To make it a little simpler on yourself, you may want to check out the Sensible Tableview, which makes all of this much easier to implement:
http://thenextweb.com/dd/2011/04/12/an-ios-developers-dream-sensible-tableview/?awesm=tnw.to_17mDs

Comment: Please note that Sensible Tableview is a commercial product.

Answer (score 1):

I'm trying to develop something like this and imagining it.
In my opinion, if you look closely, the screen seems to be composed of a vertical UIScrollView. This component will hold a UITableView with multiple sections or maybe even several UITableView components. When focusing textfields on cells, the UIScrollview scrolls the content to place the selected textfield in a more suitable/balanced .y position, for viewing and editing.

Answer (score 0):

check out these links.. they are about customizing uitableviews and are rather detailed.

http://www.e-string.com/content/custom-uitableviewcells-interface-builder

http://www.galloway.me.uk/tutorials/custom-uitableviewcell/

Answer (score 0):

It can be accomplished by customizing table views. Use the custom cells based on the section for the table view.

Answer (score -1):

No need to create your own table view.  The address book framework creates absolutely all of this and will even add contacts to the iPhone's address book too.