# Editable Grouped UITableView

Tags: iphone, uitableview

My designer wants me to implement an editable grouped tableview with functionality similar to what you see with 'ABNewPersonViewController' in the Contacts application where there are segmented table areas with add/delete buttons, etc.

Is this a standard way to edit information that is viewed in grouped tables?  If so, are there any good examples of this out there that don't involve the AddressBook UI Framework?

Thanks!

Comment: It's been asked before, but that question never got answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060501/iphone-form-like-new-contact Hopefully we get answers for this one because I'm curious too!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The design pattern using add/delete buttons on table views shows up in a couple of sample code projects from Apple that I've used. That's a good place to start.

As for "is this a standard way", I guess the answer is "yes and no". Yes because Apple certainly does it this way, but no because they don't always use this design pattern in all their table-based apps.

Comment: Thanks for your help.  Can you point me to a sample from Apple that does this on a grouped table that is not from AddressBook?

Comment: The Apple source code project "EditableDetailView" does what you want but it doesn't seem to be available for download from Apple anymore. (Indeed, the Base SDK for that project is set to 2.1!)