# Adding a sectioned tableview - Beginner

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I need to have a sectioned `tableview` like the following. I need a `section` to look like shown in the following image.

`Home` on one side, then on the other column `Street, City, state, zipcode`. And also `Country` and `state` should be on another row.

If someone could show me some sample code or a tutorial to start on this

[image]

note : you get the following UI when you are trying to add an address to a contact using your iPhone and sorry i don't have any code, i am clueless where to start.

Comment: Interesting question, I think you could do that by creating your own class that inherits from UIView and then building the sections yourself (similar to the way you build custom table cells).

Comment: I don't think it'll be that complicated. Anyway i haven't tried any other approach :S

Comment: Check out this link may be helpful to you :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3060501/iphone-form-like-new-contact

Comment: I think i know to divide a cell to 2 parts. Like `Home Page | URL`. But i don't know to create columns,sub columns and rows as shown in the above image

Comment: Ok does anyone know how to draw the verticle line between Home page and URL ( ` |  ` )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get creative. Sometimes something looks like a tableViewCell but it actually isn't one ;-)

[image]

Just a bunch of UIViews with lightGray backgroundColor and a width or height of 1. And those are arranged in cells that have different heights.

[image]

Comment: Oh, i am creating my application by using code only. This would be a nightmare then :S